# How do I both check the response status and get the resultant data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working with JavaScript for the first time in a long time for a personal project.

I'm using the Remix framework to access a separate backend, and for the `POST` requests that I make to submit data to the backend (e.g., to create a user), I'd like to both validate that the request was successful, and then grab resultant data the backend reflects back in the response.

For instance, after the user creates a new record in my system, the backend might return the created record including an ID that's assigned by the backend, so that you can redirect to the newly created document.

But as I've currently implemented this, the response data "disappears".

My current understanding is that when I call `response.ok`, that's evaluating the return promise, at which point, when I try to access it again with `response.id`, it's been "emptied."

How do I restructure this to check the request was good before I branch?

It feels a little clunky to me to do something to call the promise and then proceed.

```
export async function action({ request }: ActionArgs) {
  const body = await request.formData();

  // make the document object to submit here

  const response = await fetch("http://backend:8000/documents/create", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(document)
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    const documentId = response.id;

    return redirect("/documents/" + documentId);
  }
  else if (response.status == 400) {
    errors.document = "Document creation failed";
  }

  return json({ errors });
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to get from `response.id`? You need to do `(await response.json()).id` if you want the `id` field from the response parsed as JSON

Comment: Yep, that was it. I'm still wrapping my head around all the contours JavaScript async stuff!